# How to automate deallocation with storage pools in Ada95

Tags: ada, ada95

I read that user-defined Storage Pools can be made to simplify the deallocation process and in some cases even **automate** it. Giddy at the possibility, I have been trying to make a simple storage pool example in Ada95, but I am running into trouble.

I have been reading the following [recommended page](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Advanced&CID=222) to see an example of an implementation, and try and run it on my machine. However, after tweaking some of the `with` and `use` statements in order to get it to compile, when I ran it I saw that it actually failed on occasion and claimed that "adjust/finalize raised an error". Tweaking the exception handling to further propagate the full details I got the following message:

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : memory_management.adb:113 index check failed
```

I'm struggling with this because the `Unchecked_Deallocation` call seems to be what is providing the inaccurate object size that is resulting in an inaccurate index! The `new` call *never* reports allocating the amount that is attempting to be deallocated. As I am *very* new to this concept, I am stumped as to what to do next. If anyone is willing to point out my silly mistake or highlight something I am misunderstanding, I would be very grateful.

Here is the code after I modified it, exactly as I organized it:

**memory_management.ads**

```
with System.Storage_Pools;
with System.Storage_Elements;

package Memory_Management is
    use System;

    type User_Pool (Size : Storage_Elements.Storage_Count) is new
        System.Storage_Pools.Root_Storage_Pool with private;

    procedure Allocate (
        Pool            : in out User_Pool;
        Storage_Address :    out System.Address;
        Size_In_Storage_Elements : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;
        Alignment       : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count);

    procedure Deallocate (
       Pool            : in out User_Pool;
       Storage_Address : in     System.Address;
       Size_In_Storage_Elements : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;
       Alignment       : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count);

    function Storage_Size (Pool : in User_Pool)
        return Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;

    -- Exeption declaration
    Memory_Exhausted : exception;

    Item_Too_Big : exception;

private
    type User_Pool (Size : Storage_Elements.Storage_Count) is new
        System.Storage_Pools.Root_Storage_Pool with record
        Data       : Storage_Elements.Storage_Array (1 .. Size);
        Addr_Index : Storage_Elements.Storage_Count := 1;
    end record;
end Memory_Management;
```

**memory_management.adb**

```
with Ada.Exceptions;
with Ada.Text_Io;
with System.Storage_Elements;
with System.Address_To_Access_Conversions;

package body Memory_Management is
    use Ada;
    use Text_Io;
    use type System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;

    Package_Name: constant String := "Memory_Management.";

    -- Used to turn on/off the debug information
    Debug_On: Boolean := True;

    type Holder is record
        Next_Address: System.Address := System.Null_Address;
    end record;

    package Addr_To_Acc is new Address_To_Access_Conversions(Holder);

    -- Keep track of the size of memory block for reuse
    Free_Storage_Keeper : array (Storage_Elements.Storage_Count 
        range 1 .. 100) of System.Address := 
        (others => System.Null_Address);

    procedure Display_Info(Message       : String; 
                           With_New_Line : Boolean := True) is
    begin
       if Debug_On then
          if With_New_Line then
             Put_Line(Message);
          else
             Put(Message);
          end if;
       end if;
    end Display_Info;

    procedure Allocate(
            Pool            : in out User_Pool;
            Storage_Address :    out System.Address;
            Size_In_Storage_Elements : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;
            Alignment       : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count) is

        Procedure_Name : constant String := "Allocate";
        Temp_Address : System.Address := System.Null_Address;
        Marker : Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;
    begin

       Marker := (Size_In_Storage_Elements + Alignment - 1) / Alignment;

        if Free_Storage_Keeper(Marker) /= System.Null_Address then
            Storage_Address := Free_Storage_Keeper(Marker);
            Free_Storage_Keeper(Marker) :=
                Addr_To_Acc.To_Pointer(Free_Storage_Keeper(
                Marker)).Next_Address;
        else
            Temp_Address := Pool.Data(Pool.Addr_Index)'Address;

            Pool.Addr_Index := Pool.Addr_Index + Alignment *
                ((Size_In_Storage_Elements + Alignment - 1) / Alignment);

            Display_Info("storage elements to be allocated from pool: " &
            System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Count'Image(
            Size_In_Storage_Elements));

            Display_Info("Alignment in allocation operation: " &
            System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Count'Image(Alignment));

            -- make sure memory is available as requested
            if Pool.Addr_Index > Pool.Size then
                Exceptions.Raise_Exception(Storage_Error'Identity,
                    "Storage exhausted in " & Package_Name & 
                    Procedure_Name);
            else
                Storage_Address := Temp_Address;
            end if;
        end if;

        --Display_Info("Address allocated from pool: " &
        --    System.Storage_Elements.Integer_Address'Image(
        --    System.Storage_Elements.To_Integer(Storage_Address)));

    exception
        when Error : others => -- Object too big or memory exhausted
            Display_Info(Exceptions.Exception_Information(Error));
            raise;
    end Allocate;

    procedure Deallocate(
            Pool            : in out User_Pool;
            Storage_Address : in     System.Address;
            Size_In_Storage_Elements : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;
            Alignment       : in Storage_Elements.Storage_Count) is

        Marker : Storage_Elements.Storage_Count;
    begin

        Marker := (Size_In_Storage_Elements + Alignment - 1) / Alignment;

                --Display_Info("Address to be returned to pool: " &
        --    System.Storage_Elements.Integer_Address'Image(
        --    System.Storage_Elements.To_Integer(Storage_Address)));

        Display_Info("storage elements to return to pool: " &
            System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Count'Image(
            Size_In_Storage_Elements));

        Display_Info("Alignment to be used in deallocation: " &
            System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Count'Image(Alignment));

        Addr_To_Acc.To_Pointer(Storage_Address).Next_Address :=
            Free_Storage_Keeper(Marker);
        Free_Storage_Keeper(Marker) := Storage_Address;
    exception
        when Error: others =>
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Information(Error));
            raise;
    end Deallocate;

    function Storage_Size (Pool : in User_Pool)
        return Storage_Elements.Storage_Count is
    begin
        return Pool.Size;
    end Storage_Size;
end Memory_Management;
```

**memory_management-support.ads**

```
with Ada.Finalization;

package Memory_Management.Support is

    use Ada;

    -- Adjust the storage size according to the application
    Big_Pool : User_Pool(Size => 100);

    type Int_Acc is access Integer;
    for Int_Acc'Storage_Pool use Big_Pool;

    type Str_Acc is access all String;
    for Str_Acc'Storage_Pool use Int_Acc'Storage_Pool;

    type General_Data is new Finalization.Controlled 
    with record
        Id : Int_Acc;
        Name : Str_Acc;
    end record;

    procedure Initialize(Object : in out General_Data);

    procedure Finalize(Object : in out General_Data);

end Memory_Management.Support;
```

**memory_management-support.adb**

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;
with Ada.Exceptions;
with Ada.Text_IO;
package body Memory_Management.Support is

    procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(Integer, Int_Acc);
    procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(String, Str_Acc);

    procedure Initialize(Object : in out General_Data) is
    begin
        null;
    end Initialize;

    procedure Finalize(Object : in out General_Data) is
    begin
        Free(Object.Id);
        Free(Object.Name);
    end Finalize;

end Memory_Management.Support;
```

**memory_management_test.adb**

```
with Ada.Finalization;
with Ada.Text_Io;
with Memory_Management.Support;

procedure Memory_Management_Test is
    use Ada;
    use Text_Io;
    use Memory_Management.Support;
begin

    Put_Line ("********* Memory Control Testing Starts **********");
    for Index in 1 .. 10 loop
        declare
            David_Botton : General_Data;
            Nick_Roberts : General_Data;
            Anh_Vo : General_Data;
        begin
            David_Botton := (Finalization.Controlled with
                Id => new Integer'(111), 
                Name => new String'("David Botton"));
            Nick_Roberts := (Finalization.Controlled with
                Id => new Integer'(222), 
                Name => new String' ("Nick Roberts"));
            Anh_Vo := (Finalization.Controlled with
                Id => new Integer'(333), 
                Name => new String' ("Anh Vo"));
        end;
    end loop;

    Put_Line ("Memory Management Test Passes");
exception
    when others =>
        Put_Line ("Memory Management Test Fails");
end Memory_Management_Test;
```

lastly, here is what the output looks like upon failure:

```
********* Memory Control Testing Starts **********
storage elements to be allocated from pool:  4
Alignment in allocation operation:  4
storage elements to be allocated from pool:  20
Alignment in allocation operation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  24
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to be allocated from pool:  20
Alignment in allocation operation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  20
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to be allocated from pool:  16
Alignment in allocation operation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  16
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  12
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  12
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  8
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  20
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  20
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  16
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  12
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  238878632
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : memory_management.adb:113 index check failed

storage elements to return to pool:  4
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
storage elements to return to pool:  238878632
Alignment to be used in deallocation:  4
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : memory_management.adb:113 index check failed

Memory Management Test Fails
```

Comment: Works for me, on all the compilers I have here (macOS). What compiler are you using? what OS? what compiler switches?

Comment: @SimonWright I am using GNAT 7.3.0 with the -gnat95 switch (though I've tried compiling without that switch and it doesn't seem to matter), on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with Linux kernel version 4.15.0-43-generic

Comment: Works for me too. Must be a compiler bug where the fix has not yet made it into FSF gcc gnat 7.3.0. Easiest way forward may be to install and use GNAT Community Edition 2017 where the -gnat95 compiler flag can still be used. It has been removed in GNAT Community Edition 2018.

Comment: I can get it to fall over intermittently using gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) (that’s stretch), but not with any other compiler. Not helped by gdb problems, & that the problem doesn’t appear under gdb or valgrind. It seriously looks like a compiler problem. You could try GNAT CE 2018 (works [doesn’t fail] for me, macOS and stretch).

Comment: There is an Ada95 storage pool implementation in Deepend on source forge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/deepend/
Maybe it doesn't trigger the compiler bug you have run into @silentTee.

Comment: Aside from its unhelpful name, there’s a problem with the `Marker` variable, which is the requested size divided by the requested alignment (rounded up), and is used to index the `Free_Storage_Keeper`, presumably in an attempt to keep same-sized blocks together. But 16 bytes/alignment 4 will end in the same index as 32 bytes/alignment 8!!! Also, there’s no attempt to actually align the request. Also, I think you need an `Adjust` for `General_Data`. Also, `Free_Storage_Keeper` ought to live in the storage pool. I think I’ll switch off now (2130 hours!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stand by my remarks in the comments above, that the following problems exist:

- The `Marker` variable, which is the requested size divided by the requested alignment (rounded up), and is used to index the `Free_Storage_Keeper`, presumably in an attempt to keep same-sized blocks together. But 16 bytes/alignment 4 will end in the same index as 32 bytes/alignment 8.
- There’s no attempt to actually align the request.
- You need an `Adjust` for `General_Data` (you always need an `Adjust` for a `Controlled` type containing pointers).
- `Free_Storage_Keeper` ought to live in the storage pool (what happens if you have two instances of `User_Pool`? what about tasks?)

However, I think the immediate cause of the crash is this statement in `Deallocate`:

```
Addr_To_Acc.To_Pointer(Storage_Address).Next_Address :=
   Free_Storage_Keeper(Marker);
```

because it assumes that a pointer can fit in an allocation, which is certainly not the case with an `Integer` on a 64-bit OS (4-byte integer vs 8-byte access).

You could start by forcing a minimum allocation in `Allocate`, `Deallocate`:

```
  Size : constant Storage_Elements.Storage_Count
    := Storage_Elements.Storage_Count'Max
      (Size_In_Storage_Elements,
       System.Address'Max_Size_In_Storage_Elements);
```

and then use `Size` instead of `Size_In_Storage_Elements` throughout.